# Stored procedure joining a table function?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that needs to do an inner join on a function that returns a table.  Trying to call it like so:

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[udf_GetBillingInfo(@QuoteID)] billInfo ON quotes.QuoteID = billInfo.QuoteID
```

gives an error `invalid object name dbo.udf_GetBillingInfo(@QuoteID)`

Given my requirements I don't think I can just make the function into a view as it has a minor bit of logic in it.  How can I join the result?  Would I have to assign the function result to a variable or something of that nature?

Comment: you should be able to join to a TVF. you sure schema and tvf name is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the square brackets - `[dbo].[udf_GetBillingInfo(@QuoteID)]` - they quote whatever is inside as the function name.

Change it to this:

```
[dbo].udf_GetBillingInfo(@QuoteID)
```

Comment: Hah, that was it; I forgot that [] denotes a **column** name, so it was thinking the name of the function *and* the parameter was a column.  Failz.

Comment: or [dbo].[udf_GetBillingInfo](@QuoteID)

Comment: D'oh! I can't believe I missed that one!  +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an (dumb) example of joining to a TVF, hope it helps!

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunc ( @p1 int ) RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
        SELECT @p1 AS a 
        union 
        SELECT @p1 +1 AS a 
        union 
        SELECT @p1 +2 AS a
)
GO

declare @t table (c int) 
insert @t (c) values(1),(2),(3),(4)

select * 
from @t t 
left join dbo.MyFunc(1) f on  t.c = f.a
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you write you function as a table function? I think you may find the answer here

[tsql returning a table from a function or store procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440308/tsql-returning-a-table-from-a-function-or-store-procedure)

Comment: Indeed. Having re-read the question I can see you actually said it was a table function.