# Can't create stored procedure with table output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have this code:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[GetProfitDeals]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProfitDealsVar2]
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'TableOrderType' AND is_table_type = 1 AND SCHEMA_ID('dbo') = schema_id)
DROP TYPE [dbo].[TableOrderType];

CREATE TYPE TableOrderType AS TABLE(
    Order_ID int NOT NULL,
    Order_AccNumber int NOT NULL,
    Order_OpenDate datetime NULL,
    Order_CloseDate datetime NULL,
    Order_Profit float NULL
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProfitDeals](@OpenDate datetime = NULL, @CloseDate datetime  = NULL, @MinProfit float = NULL, @out TableOrderType OUTPUT READONLY)
AS
    INSERT INTO @out
    SELECT * FROM [Orders]
    WHEN [Orders].[OpenDate] >= @OpenDate
GO
```

But I get the error "Incorrrect syntax about construction 'READONLY'". How I can fix this, because me I really need a OUTPUT table parameter.

Comment: Would just `SELECT * FROM [Orders]...` in the procedure and dumping that to some sort of DataTable serve the same purpose? I'm sure you've figured it out in the last 7 years... =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Table parameters are readonly. You cannot select into them. [Use Table-Valued Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx):

> Table-valued parameters must be passed as input READONLY parameters to Transact-SQL routines. You cannot perform DML operations such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT on a table-valued parameter in the body of a routine.

And [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx):

> You cannot return data in a table-valued parameter. Table-valued parameters are input-only; the OUTPUT keyword is not supported.

Read [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) for a comprehensive discussion on alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

As Remus states, you can't do that exactly but you could accomplish what you want to achieve by using a User-Defined Function instead:
[tsql returning a table from a function or store procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440308/tsql-returning-a-table-from-a-function-or-store-procedure)

Which will return your data in a table however I believe you will need to define the table in the Function and not define it as a type