# Looping table valued parameter values passed as parameter to stored procedure for checking a value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have a stored procedure that receives a TVP as input. Now, I need to check the received data for a particular ID in a primary key column. If it exists, then I just need to update the table using those new values for other column (sent via TVP). Else, do an insert.

How to do it?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC 
    @tvp MyTable READONLY
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MYTAB WHERE ID= @tvp.ID)
         DO update
    ELSE
         Create
```

Just wondering the `if exists` loop I did is correct. I reckon its wrong as it will only check for first value and then update. What about other values? How should I loop through this?

Comment: @lad2025: We can not use TVP for output values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270727/cant-create-stored-procedure-with-table-output-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Looping/CURSOR is the weapon of last resort, always search for solution that is `SET based`, not `ROW based`.

You should use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) which is designed for this type of operation:

```
MERGE table_name AS TGT
USING (SELECT * FROM @tvp) AS SRC
   ON TGT.id = SRC.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET col = SRC.col
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (col_name, col_name2, ...)
   VALUES (SRC.col_name1, SRC.col_name2, ...)
```

If you don't like MERGE use INSERT/UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col = tv.col,
    ...
FROM table_name AS tab
JOIN @tvp AS tv
   ON tab.id = tv.id


INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, ...)
SELECT tv.col1, tv.col2, ...
FROM table_name AS tab
RIGHT JOIN @tvp AS tv
  ON tab.id = tv.id
WHERE tab.id IS NULL
```