# Returning tables in UDF

Tags: sql-server, udf, dynamic-tables

I am new to SQL Server and I would like to know how to return the exact columns of tables in UDFs.

The situation is like this : I am going to query a table and then return it again as table.

Example :

```
create function test
var t
set t = select * from table where condition
return t;
```

How am I going to do it?

(question is only how to return the table with dynamic fields)

Hope you understand the question. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** : my question is somehow like how do I create a table variable where its columns are dynamic.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440308/tsql-returning-a-table-from-a-function-or-store-procedure?

Comment: @Ralph I updated my question. kindly take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User defined functions` have [several limitations](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/) (they are meant not to have side-effects - cannot anything in the database - etc.). For your particular case, the following prohibit you to do your work:

- dynamic SQL cannot be used
- temporary tables are not allowed

So, a function can only work if it knows what is the structure of the result at compile time.

I would consider a procedure to achieve what you need, since it allows more flexibility. However, this comes with the headache of sharing data between [stored procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

It is not specified in the question, but ideally, this dynamic processing should stay in a high level language like `C#` or `Java` that have more support for dynamic structures (e.g. `LINQ` or `Dynamic LINQ` in `C#`)