# Table-valued function refresh

Tags: sql-server, database-metadata

I have a table-valued function (TVF) in SQL Server that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TVF_xyz(@AuditKey INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        SELECT *
        FROM xyz 
        WHERE AUDIT_KEY = @AuditKey
GO
```

Now, I added a new column to the `xyz` table.

When I query using `TVF_xyz`, it doesn't show me the new column (shows all other columns except newly added).

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM TVF_xyz (1543)
```

I would like to know, how to refresh TVF to show new column.

PS: `Select *` used in TVF to fetch all columns.

Comment: Hi masta rhian, how do I refresh view? 'xyz' is a table and when I query this table directly, I can see new field populated.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440308/tsql-returning-a-table-from-a-function-or-store-procedure help you

Comment: Well, there are 930 fields, writing them explicitly is a nightmare. Also, there are few more tables, for which I need to add a column. I'm wondering, why it doesn't show up a new column? I thought, TVF executes function everytime it is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After bit of searching, I found [sp_refreshsqlmodule (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754(v=sql.110).aspx), its common behavior of TVF.

In order to refresh TVF, following SP needs to be executed:

```
EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule 'TVF_xyz'
```

Comment: normally you wouldn't...  but as per msdn Therefore, the returned rowset structure is implicitly defined.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your statement. As per MS Technet page (link in my answer) sp_refreshsqlmodule is for:                                                                Updates the metadata for the specified non-schema-bound stored procedure, user-defined function, view, DML trigger, database-level DDL trigger, or server-level DDL trigger in the current database. Persistent metadata for these objects, such as data types of parameters, can become outdated because of changes to their underlying objects.

Comment: i guess to avoid that scenario MSDN suggested to define the table structure because as a standard we dont use SELECT *

Comment: I'm not sure, how that is related to my question. However, I'm happy that, I could understand how TVF works and how to refresh metadata.

Comment: It's quite important though because we dont normally refresh medata after altering something. That's if you want to streamline your process.

Comment: Well, in general, using explicit column names make sense. However, in my case, I've 930 fields and I do know, I'm about to add another field and ready to cater metadata changes down the line. Anyways, thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386954(v=vs.110).aspx

> The following SQL function explicitly states that it returns a TABLE. Therefore, the returned rowset structure is implicitly defined.

sample

```
CREATE FUNCTION ProductsCostingMoreThan(@cost money)  
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN  
    SELECT ProductID, UnitPrice  
    FROM Products  
    WHERE UnitPrice > @cost
```