# Syntax error while writing function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Here I'm trying to write a function for extracting each digit from a number and return a table with column UserId and Number. But i'm getting syntax error. Logic is working i'm just unable to arrange things in proper manner.
If i pass userid as akshay and number as 1234 so this function must return a table as
akshay 1
akshay 2
akshay 3
akshay 4

Comment: Add code and errormessages as text not as link to an image

Comment: `(MS)SQL-Server` is not `mysql`. Please remove unrelated tags

Comment: by != do you mean <>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define variable for the return table

```
RETURNS  @returnTable TABLE 
(

   UserId varchar(20),
   ModNumber smallint

)
```

Please check this reference : [tsql returning a table from a function or store procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440308/tsql-returning-a-table-from-a-function-or-store-procedure)

Comment: Ramesh thankyou but now m getting error on Create Function Line "Incorrect Syntax: Create Function must be the only statement in the batch"

Comment: @akshaysahu You need to add RETURN before the END statement

Comment: Please don't ask question before search in google: https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=shB0WtCYL4q6vwTNpLnYDA&q=Create+Function+must+be+the+only+statement+in+the+batch&oq=Create+Function+must+be+the+only+statement+in+the+batch&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1.654.654.0.2226.2.1.0.0.0.0.214.214.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.213.0...0.UjD3KUXSfmU